# Assembly that expose classes from other

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, dll, .net-assembly

I have 3rdparty A1.dll, A2.dll with classes AClass.
I reference it from my B1 and B2 dlls, but I want to to it another way:
I want to have my X.dll using A1+A2 and B1, B2 using X. It is important that all namespaces and classes should be the same in X and A1+A2.

**EDIT:**
X should be my copy of A1, A2 - I can even use X1, X2. Then I can use one license of A1, A2 - for X, not for all exec&dlls I would use in der future.

Comment: We probably need more details and perhaps some specific code to comment on this, it isn't telling us a great deal

Answer (score 2):

So if I understand you correctly you want X.DLL to stand in for the 3rd party DLL's.  You can achieve this with an [Adapter pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern).  The fact that you want to preserve all namespaces and classes is quite scary.  Those collisions are going to be quite troublesome.  You will likely have to resort to [using aliasing directives](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx) to maintain some level of sanity.  (Why would you do this if you have control of B.DLL and X.DLL?)

That being said here is a pattern for X.DLL adapters which does not use a collision naming scheme...

```
class Adapter: IAdapter//Adapter is a member of X.DLL
{
     public AClass aClassMember = new AClass();//A.DLL or A2.DLL member
     public void ExposeAClass() {};
}
```

Then you can reference X.DLL from B.DLL.

```
   class BClass
   {
        public IAdapter myAdapter = new Adapter();//Access X's adapter to expose A.  Could take a step further with dependency injection...
   }
```

The dependency diagram would look like this (give or take the interfaces.dll)

[image]

Comment: It is not what I need. Programmers should not have to referenced from A, but "feel like" almost do. If A changes then X does not have to be changed.

Comment: @GerhardSchmitt - I think you misread the chart and/or answer. Programmers will need to reference B (or X depending on what you are doing) only. That part works just like plain old n-tier. The B.DLL project references X which in turn references the 3rd party DLL's. Changes are hidden from B.DLL by the Adapter Pattern used in X...

Comment: But all changes in A would make changes in X. If sb add new class to A.

Comment: @GerhardSchmitt - Correct.  A is a 3rd party DLL which means you have no control over when they decide to update that DLL with a new version.  There's no stopping that fact.  You can either continue to use the old version of A or contain the changes so they have the smallest possible effect with decoupling.  That's exactly the point of the Adapter pattern.  When a change is made then you have to update the implementation in X.DLL.  A well designed interface remains unchanged so B.DLL remains unaware of changes in A.DLL.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean: A1.dll & A2.dll are defining the same type name in the same namespace, and you're having troubles when you want to reference both A1 & A2 in X.dll and use one of these two types ?

To solve that, you could use "extern aliases". That's a quite unknown feature of C#:

Add an extern alias on the dll you ant (right click on assembly's reference -> properties)

[image: extern alias]

And then, **at the top** of your .cs file, just put:

```
extern alias myAlias;
using okType = myAlias::DuplicateNamespace.DuplciateType;
```

and use it in the code:

```
var my = new okType();
```

ps: My answer may be irrelevant if I misunderstood you :)

Comment: Thank you, but that is not that.